# Getting res/layout/launch_screen.xml in React native after installing react-native-splash-screen

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I'm getting the below error message. I was able to install the package and configured it.
However, I am getting this error just after I see the splash screen. [image]

Comment: Did you get any luck fixing it?